# Self operator override - Return by reference or return by copy

Tags: c++

Consider the following code?

I was wondering, if I change it from (Function body still the same)

```
error_code& operator|=(const error_code &e)
```

to

```
error_code operator|=(const error_code &e)
```

Is there any potential bug that might possible occur? The only difference I see is, it will perform an extra copy operation, other than that, no big deal.

So, should I just stick to return by reference, or it doesn't matter?

---

```
class error_code {
public:
 error_code() : hi(0), lo(0) {}
 error_code(__int64 lo) : hi(0), lo(lo) {}
 error_code(__int64 hi, __int64 lo) : hi(hi), lo(lo) {}

 // How about return by copy?
 error_code& operator|=(const error_code &e) {
  this->hi |= e.hi;
  this->lo |= e.lo;
  return *this;
 }

 __int64 hi;
 __int64 lo;
};

error_code operator|(const error_code& e0, const error_code& e1) {
 return error_code(e0.hi | e1.hi, e0.lo | e1.lo); 
}

int main() {
 error_code e0(1);
 error_code e1(2);
 e0 |= e1;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to change that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there any potential bug that might possible occur?

Yes. This won't work as expected anymore:

```
(ec |= x) = y;
```

Now, this is a silly piece of code, no doubt about that, but

1. it *does* work for other types and
2. there might be other cases where this difference matters.

For example, if your class `error_code` will have member functions modifying the object they are invoked for, then these will modify a temporary object if you return by copy instead of reference:

```
(ec |= x).normalize();  // whatever "normalizing" error code means...
```

Comment: +1 on this. Yan, try to be consistent with the operators' behaviour for the other types.

Comment: so, return by reference is the only "zen" of this kind of situation?

Comment: @Yan: A golden rule of operator overloading: __If in doubt, do as the ints do.__ For `int`, `(a|=b)=c` works. (BTW, here's a shameless plug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading.)

Comment: @Yan: yes, you captured it perfectly with the keyword `zen`. It's not mandatory, but unless you have very good reasons (writing a DSEL is usually taken as one, at least by the authors) try not to break people assumptions.

Comment: @sbi `(ec |= x).normalize();` This should be illegal if returning a temporary unless `normalize()` is `const`.

Comment: @RedX: You can invoke non-`const` member functions on temporary objects of user-defined types.

Comment: @RedX: Temporaries are perfectly mutable, you just can't refer to them with mutable references, which is just as stupid as it sounds, and you can take const references to them, but you can't take their address.

Answer (score 1):

It would mean that anything you then do with the returned object would not affect the original object any more. And the other way round - the returned object would never reflect changes done to the original object. This is a typical issue of value vs identity. You are keeping a copy of the object's value, but you're losing its identity.